# CentOS route настройка

Tags: apache, сервер, centos, маршрутизация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что необходимо сделать в такой ситуации: есть 2 ПК (Win7 и CentOS 6) + DIR 615 и выделенный IP; роутер  выдает адреса по DHCP --192.168.0.10 и 192.168.0.11, также имеется доменное имя в зоне .**ru**.  Доменное имя связано с выделенным **IP 91.200.xxx.xxx.**   На CentOS (192.168.0.11) стоит сервер. Вопрос вот в чем  как сделать так чтобы при наборе имени http://www.xxxxx.ru пользователь попадал на адрес 192.168.0.11 ( CentOS ) т.е как связать адрес 192.168.0.11 с доменным именем, какие файлы нужно корректировать и что изменять. Если можно поподробнее.  Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 3):

В длинке надо настроить проброс порта (портов). На пример, при обращении к 80 порту по адресу 91.200.xxx.xxx, длинк будет перенаправлять на 192.168.0.11 порт 80.

Comment: А как? не могу найти эту функцию. Сейчас такая ситуация -- при наборе адреса 91.200.ххх.ххх -попадаю на стартовую страницу длинка,апри наборе доменного имени пишит:  BlockedAccess to the requested URL http://хххххх.ru/ was not allowed (bad redirect).

Comment: Все спасибо разобрался не обратил внимания на одну функцию в DIRe 615,правда по ай-пи (91.200.ххх.ххх) все равно заходит на стартовую Длинка; кстати аналогичный вопрос рассматривался http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/1482/

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню в 615 нету прямых настроек на проброс портов, надо прописывать маршруты руками.И ваще галимый роутер, купил по неосторожности, выручил только прошивка ddwrt и то таки раз в 3 дня теряет wifi пока не перезагрузишь из под рута)

Comment: Голимый - не голимый,но пока приходится пользоваться,и могу сказать, тьфу-тьфу, что пока,что нареканий нет,а проброс там можно сделать по другому -- там есть функция "Разместить сайт" так вот через нее.Прошивкой DDWRT угробил пару железок поэтому наступать вновь на те же грабли не хотелось бы P.S За полтора месяца перезагружал один раз и то когда настраивал WI-FI сейчас на нем (DIRe) висит два ПК и ТВ + Wi-Fi на несколько точек   Скорее всего просто попался качественный

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен доступ из интернета к серверу, тогда нужно на CentOS поднимать DNS сервер и к нему прикручивать доменное имя, иначе доступ только по IP адресу!

Comment: Детальнее можно,а то я не шибко силен в DNS

Comment: Не нужно тут ничего, товаришь глупость написал